# Setting the state from a callback in the parent component doesn't work

Tags: react-hooks, material-ui

I'm trying to set the state from the parent component using a callback. This callback gets passed down to the child component that renders a material ui datatable. The callback responds onClick and passes some values to the callback. The problem is that setting the state with the values from the callback arguments doesn't work.

My assumption is that when the user clicks the button from the child component, it should invoke the callback function and pass the values I needed to set the state.

Parent Component:

```
export default function ViewJobs() {
        const [type, setType] = useState('');
        const [params, setParams] = useState({});
    
        const callback = ({ cellValues, componentType, path }) => {
            setType(componentType);
            setParams(cellValues)   // Sets the params with an object.
            console.log(cellValues) // Displays the data I need in the console
            history.push(path);
        };

        console.log(params) // Displays undefine in the console.
        
        return(
           <React.Fragment>
                <TabPanel value={value} index={0} dir={theme.direction} >
                     <DataTable
                         jobs={job}
                         title='All'
                         parentCallback={callback}
                     />
               </TabPanel>
           </React.Fragment>
        );
}
```

Child Component

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function DataTable(props) {
  const { jobs, parentCallback } = props;
  const rows = jobs.payload;

  const handleDiaryClick = (event, cellValues) => {
    const params = {
      cellValues,
      componentType: 'diary',
      path: "/view/jobs/diary"
    };
    
    parentCallback(params);
  };

  const renderDiaryElement = params => {

    return (
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        style={{ backgroundColor: "#000000" }}
        onClick={(event) => {
          handleDiaryClick(event, params);
        }}
      >
        <MenuBookIcon />
      </Button>
    );
  }


  return (
    <div
      className={classes.root}
      style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}
    >
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        //checkboxSelection
        disableSelectionOnClick
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Since the state has been lifted up to the parent component, I'm under the impression that the code above should be working.

I tried to reproduce the issue but I couldn't replicate it.
Any advice or inputs are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further checking on my codebase, I found that the history.push(path) located in my callback is causing the issue. I had to remove this line of code for it to work.